# Discord.js Slash Command permissions

Tags: discord.js

I want to create Slash Command Permissions on my Bot, so that the Command is grey for those who don´t have permissions for the Command, but I don´t find anything usefull for this problem.
I using the Command-Handler from discordjs.guide
[This is my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abWxA.png)

Comment: Please post the code in your question and not as a link :)

Comment: Also, have you already read this [article](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-command-permissions.html#user-permissions)?

Comment: code as a link would at least be salvageable, but code is beyond saving. please edit your question!

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I may not help you, but I do not know the exact answer to your question, but I suggest you to use [Worm Off Keys](https://docs.wornoffkeys.com/), using it is very easy, You can set permission in the command file by using `permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR']`, in the command properties, and you can get/reply to the user in easy way:

```js
    const user = message : message ? interaction;
    user.reply({ content: "properties test" })
```

This is just an example.

Comment: yes, I could use this, but I want to use discord.js and nothing else